# Getting Exception "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;" in selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium4

I am using `selenium "4.0.0-rc-2"` with `chrome 89` . While selecting value from drop down using select class, getting exception:

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;".

Comment: Hi @V Sri, Did this issue resolved for you? If yes, can you please share your points?